# Any working techniques or examples for a multistep AJAX enabled node form

Tags: nodes, ajax, forms

There's an AJAX enabled multistep form in the [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) and another in [Chaos Tools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) (ctools_ajax_sample.module) In both cases the form is built in the function and doesn't use the default core node form.

Closer to what I'm after is [a multistep node form](http://drupal4hu.com/node/246) using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() but this one isn't AJAX.

Is it possible to use `hook_form_alter()` to create a multistep node form that is AJAX enabled, or should I build my multistep form independently, then use `drupal_form_submit()` or a new node object to save the data?

Drupal 7

Comment: Essentially, I can work out how to build a mutistep node form that refreshes the entire page at each step of the form, but I can't work out how to reload only the form itself with each step using the default core node form structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think trying to use multistep, ajax and the core node form may be quite tricky. I am not going to say impossible, but I think it would be a lot of work.

I would think using a custom form and saving the node as you suggest may be easier, what you'll loose with this is the flexibility of having it integrated, so if you add a new field to the node, you will need to change your form.

Comment: The main problem with making a custom form then adding a node programatically is that it won't be used when editing the node. I'd need to also set up a menu item to call my custom form and hide the core links for adding a node of this type so that two options were not available in the menus. That seems like a lot of side stepping around core behavior to achieve a form reload rather than a page reload.